# Memory leak submitting lambda to thread with copied list

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, guava

I have some simple code that polls for messages in a dedicated thread, batches them in a list and then passes said list to a different thread in order to do something which involves blocking. Here's a simplified rough approximation:

```
class MessageProcessor extends MessagePoller implements Runnable {

  private final ExecutorService batchHandlerExec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); 
  private final List<Operation> operations = new ArrayList();

  //just to indicate this is a thread started somewhere
  public void run() { while(true) processMessage(); }

  public void processMessage() {
    Message msg = poll();

    operations.add(Operation.buildFrom(msg));

    if(operations.size() >= SOME_NUMBER) {
      List<Operations> batch = ImmutableCopy.copyOf(operations);

      batchHandlerExec.submit(() -> doSomethingBlockingWith(batch));

      operations.clear(); 
    }
  }
}
```

So theres two threads, one consuming messages and another doing stuff. The issue is that given a couple days, these threads would stop running (without spring dying though, I use spring boot)

Long story short, Im suspecting a memory leak killing my MessageProcessor and while Im analyzing heap dumps and such, It'd be very helpful if anyone could point anything I may be missing on this piece of code. In particular:

- I think the `Operation`s are not being collected, does `clear()` work? Im using a Guava ImmutableList copy without releasing it, but I assumed that it would be collected since `doSomethingBlockingWith()` goes out scope after doing whatever it does
- My real executor service is as singleThreadExecutor too, so maybe Im enqueing more work to `submit()` that it can handle (batches are maybe come faster than they are processed) and thats whats filling the heap?

I've used *jvisualvm* and profiled a bit, enabled verbose garbage collector, used jmap and stuff but all the information seems to cryptic for me. So far my heap seems to be always full with strings, longs and stuff that seems to be held by `Operation` but I dont know. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Tasks will pile up in the work queue of your executor if they're generated faster than `doSomethingBlockingWith(batch)` can process them. The simplest fix would be to run the operation synchronously in your `MessageProcessor` thread.

Comment: you could cleanup your operations prior to submission for somthing. that is move the operations.clear prior to batch submission. because you have already made a copy of that so its unnecessary to keep till processing. Or else create new list with in the run method so that every batch new  list of operations will be created. Another solution is just push it into simple queue and another thread will fetch the job from that queue and do its work. So that job pulling and pushing is separated and easy to handle.